# Android Broadcast receiver not receiving when press back button

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I want to received sms when my application is minimized by back button,when I minimized by home button then it received sms,but when press button then not received broadcast messages.
Thanks.

My app code are :

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
 super.onPause();
 unregisterReceiver(receiver);
 }
```

and

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String address = "";
    String message = "";
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");

        for (int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; i++) {
            SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) smsExtra[i]);
            message += sms.getMessageBody();
            address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Received>>" + message +"From >>" + address,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

SO how can I received sms when minimized by back button thanks.

Comment: Register in your manifest

Comment: Its not working ...
unregisterReceiver(receiver);
And add receiver in manifest but not working,not receiving sms when back button press....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're unregistering the broadcast receiver when the user leaves obviously its not going to work. Instead of registering at the app level, register it in the manifest. That way its not dependent on the state of the application.

To learn more:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: Read my updated post @ShadaKalo I will **not** post a sample.

Comment: the content is not clear to me that how to do it in android manifest.

Comment: Its not working ... unregisterReceiver(receiver); And add receiver in manifest but not working,not receiving sms when back button press.

Answer (score 3):

I did it in a small tricky way,
like this.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Display confirmation here, finish() activity.
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```